# Чат сервер + клиенты

Tags: чат, linux

Какой лучше использовать чат? Для компании. Внутренняя сеть и разрешать из вне им пользоваться. Чат сервер + клиенты. Сервер на Alt Linux.

Answer (score 1):

OpenFire? Jabber-сервер, транспорт до ICQ (говорят можно и другие протоколы подключить), конференции (чат-комнаты), всякие боты типа викторины и погоды :)Сам использую под FreeBSD 8, но есть серверное ПО и под линукс, и под windows.